# Java Mail Body-Search doesn't work with certain strings in Office365 postbox

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap, office365

#### Part of the Email & Code

```
Guten Tag eWZrAiUDKYtJVCHrzkktyzVSpU,
<br><br>herzlich Willkommen bei my adfwerdsfqefd!
<br>Damit Sie Ihre Registrierung abschließen können, klicken Sie bitte auf folgenden Bestätigungslink:
<br><a href="https://local.asdfgh.asdfghjklqw.com/asdfgh-asd/registration/emailConfirm.xhtml?customerId=978860685620&amp;code=ykAuRtnqa15qncbvDoX4Cer385eu5Nnh6vnXnq3t&amp;email=asd.test%2BasdfgsTEST_NvrD%40asdfghjklqwe.com">
     https://local.asdfgh.asdfghjklqw.com/asdfgh-asd/registration/emailConfirm.xhtml?customerId=978860685620&amp;code=ykAuRtnqa15qncbvDoX4Cer385eu5Nnh6vnXnq3t&amp;email=asd.test%2BasdfgsTEST_NvrD%40asdfghjklqwe.com
</a>
```

Here are some code-snippets of the bodysearch:

```
final List<String> mails = CatchallMailBox.checkMailsUntilMatchedForDefaultWaitTime() 
            .byBodyFragment("TEST_SlYi")
            .andExtractBodyTexts();
assertThat(mails, hasSize(1));
```

-

```
public CatchallMailBox byBodyFragment(final String text) {
    searchTerms.add(new BodyTerm(text));

    return this;
}
```

-

```
inboxFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

if (searchTerms.isEmpty() && bodyTerms.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("At least one search term must be provided!");
}

final Message[] messagesArray = inboxFolder.search(new AndTerm(searchTerms.toArray(new BodyTerm[] {})));
```

#### Behavior

In the code above if I search by the BodyTerm `jJHSpdQVlrrswGkdUjKBsBPvwl` it works just as expected.

With `TEST_SlYi` (it is in the end of the link) it does not work, as in no e-mail is found. **But** if I search after `TEST[_]SlYi` it works just fine (`[TEST_SlYi]` does not work tho.) Also `TEST*SlYi` works.

I observed the same behavior with `-` and `!` (they work with `[]` or `*`). `/` and `:`  works without anything and `%` never works. (I am not sure what this tells me.)

No for example what surprisingly does not work is `sTEST` (also part of the email in the end), as I first thought it has to do something with special characters.

All in all, I have no clue what could cause this strange behavior as I see no pattern.

#### Office365

We are assuming the problem is on Microsoft's end, as we used the **exact** same code on GMail before and there it worked. We contacted Microsoft already about the problem but they could provide no (useful) answer.

I have been stuck with this bug for nearly a week, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dump the actual Unicode code points or chars of the message, so you are sure there is no invisible sign, Cyrillic T or whatever. With respect to special characters: that could be a regular expression search, the same as %, _ being special chars for SQL LIKE.

Comment: Yep, is a [pattern](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/BodyTerm.html#BodyTerm-java.lang.String-).

Comment: I don't have "access" to the messages, the search happens serverside, so I can't change the message. If it is a pattern shouldn't `[TEST_SlYi]` also work?

Comment: While the JavaMail API takes a parameter called "pattern", the IMAP protocol supports only substring searches, not anything like a regular expression search.  Of course, some IMAP servers don't strictly follow the IMAP protocol and may support some kinds of regular expressions.  It looks like that's what Office365 is doing.  Perhaps the Exchange or Outlook documentation will tell you what kinds of search strings it supports?  Note also the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) will show you exactly what IMAP commands are being sent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we already assumed something wierd is going on on their side. We're using the debug output, but couldn't get any useful there either. We decided to pull all emails and to the matching local.